# Finding the main argument of a solution

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

When solving the equation $z^3+1=-i\sqrt3$, the main argument of one of its solutions is:

a-) $\pi/3$

b-) $4\pi/9$

c-) $7\pi/9$

d-) $-2\pi/3$

I'm having trouble trying to solve the exercise because I don't really know what the question means by "main argument". Any help is welcome

Comment: It should be defined in your text.  I haven't seen the term, but would guess it is an angle in the range $[0,2\pi)$ or perhaps $[-\pi,\pi)$.  In the second case the closed end could be the top.

Comment: I think as principal and main are synonymous, they're asking to find the principal argument of the complex number. Then as Ross commented, it lies in the range $[-\pi,\pi)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**
\begin{align*}
z^{3} + 1 = -i\sqrt{3} \Longleftrightarrow z^{3} = -1 - i\sqrt{3} = 2\left(-\frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = 2\left[\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)\right]
\end{align*}